# Strange UUID reversal from fetchUuidsWithSdp

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, uuid, endianness

I have a python bluetooth server (using PyBluez) running on a raspberry pi. The uuid I use in the server is:

`8f86d132-4ab8-4c15-b8df-0b70cf10ea56`

I am calling [`device.fetchUuidsWithSdp()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#fetchUuidsWithSdp()) on the bluetooth server in my Android app. When it eventually fetches the uuids, they have been reversed in groups of two (it seems the endianness has changed).

*In the broadcast receiver:*

```
Parcelable[] uuids = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
if (uuids != null) {
    if (uuids.length > 0) {
         for (Parcelable uuid : uuids) {
              Utilities.err(uuid.toString());
         }
    } else {
         Utilities.err("no uuids");
    }
}
```

For example:

`8f86d132-4ab8-4c15-b8df-0b70cf10ea56` -> `56ea10cf-700b-dfb8-154c-b84a32d1868f`

look at the first two characters `8f`, they are the last two characters of the reversed uuid.

look at the second two characters `86`, they are the second last two characters of the reversed uuid

**What is causing this?**

Does this have anything do to with the UUID being little or big-endian?

Answer (score 5):

are you by any chance experiencing this on android version 6.0.1?
sadly there seems to be a bug in android causing this.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197341

Comment: Aye that's exactly the same problem! Thanks for the link

Comment: [Here is a workaround I use for this bug](https://gist.github.com/masterjefferson/10922165432ec016a823e46c6eb382e6). It does seem that they just aren't converting from little endian.

Answer (score 0):

your uuid is in version 4 and your variante is little Endianess. It's normal.  Depend's of your system. If you want big Endianess put `8f86d132-4ab8-4c15-88df-0b70cf10ea56`

I change the b to 8.