# Bluetooth can't find custom service UUID in SDP query

Tags: android, bluetooth, kotlin

I've got a bit of my app that is dedicated to sharing files between devices over bluetooth using a quick, ad-hoc protocol that I put together. Currently, in the containing `Activity` I begin discovery, and add any device that I find into a RecyclerView. Here is the code for the `BroadcastReceiver` that is handling that:

```
private val scanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND) {
            val dev = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            Log.d(TAG, "Got device ${dev.name} with address ${dev.address}")
            if (dev.name != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Found nonnull device name, adding")
                if (!viewAdapter.dataset.any { it.name == dev.name }) {
                    viewAdapter.dataset.add(dev)
                    viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to modify this in such a way that it would only add devices who were broadcasting with the service UUID that I set up in the server portion of the app. After doing some research I came to [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#fetchUuidsWithSdp()) that I could use to get the UUIDs of the services on the device. I integrated that into my BroadcastReceiver as such

```
private val scanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when (intent.action) {
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                val dev = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                Log.d(TAG, "Got device ${dev.name} with address ${dev.address}")
                if (dev.name != null) {
                    dev.fetchUuidsWithSdp()
                }
            }

            //TODO: Untested code
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID -> {
                val id = intent.getParcelableExtra<ParcelUuid>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID)
                if (id.uuid == ShareServerSocket.SERVICE_UUID) {
                    val dev = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    if (!viewAdapter.dataset.any { it.name == dev.name }) {
                        viewAdapter.dataset.add(dev)
                        viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(With requisite modifications to the `IntentFilter` I'm registering it with).

The code in the new branch gets called, I validated that with some debugging output. However, the `ParcelUuid[]` that I am given never contains the UUID of my service, and the device therefore never gets added. If I keep the entire setup the same on the device acting as a server, and bypass the new check on the client, I am able to connect and interact just fine. I'm unsure as to why my service wouldn't be being shown at this point.

P.S. I did also check the SDP cache, my service UUID is not there, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was running into the same issue as described in [Strange UUID reversal from fetchUuidsWithSdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339982/strange-uuid-reversal-from-fetchuuidswithsdp). Stealing that workaround made it work.